# Spring Security Test @WithMockUser not working

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, spring-security

I'm writing unit tests for my application and one of the steps I do inside my Service is get the currently authenticated user from SpringSecurityContext.

I know that if I want to mock Spring Security Authentication I can use @WithMockUser but it's not working for me as it is always returning null when the tested method reaches the getAuthentication() method call...

I've already search many SO questions and many blogs post but none of them has a solution.
I annotate my Test class with @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)

I'd like to avoid having to write 4 lines to mock a single method call

// mock Authentication
// mock Principal
// when SpringContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication -> return Authentication
// when getPrincipal() -> return Principal

edit:

Test class

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class SegmetnServiceTest {
    
    @InjectMocks
    private SegmentService service;


    @Test
    void testWithMockUser() {
            //given
            UpdateSegmentReq request = new UpdateSegmentReq();
            String name = "TEST"
            request.setName(name)

            //when
            SegmentNode segment = service.updateSegment(request);

            //then
            assertEquals(segment.getName(), name)
    }
}
```

Service class

```
public class SegmentService {

    private SegmentRepository repository;

    SegmentNode updateSegment(String code){
        SegmentNode segment = repository.findByCode(code);

        String userId = (String) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        segment.updatedBy(userId);


        return segment;
    }
}
```

The problem is, even if I annotate my Test method with @WithMockUser, when it reaches the service method getAuthentication is null and getPrincipal throws NPE.

Comment: Without seeing your test this is going to be impossible to answer.

Comment: done! @M.Deinum

Comment: You aren't using anything Spring related in that test (you are only using Mockito) so annotating it with `@WithMockUser` will do nothing.

Comment: Ok, I suspected it's something Spring Context related but what if I want to keep my unit tests light, what are the minimum annotations I should add? I'm using JUnit 5 by the way. Thanks @M.Deinum

Comment: You can always just set the context yourself and don't forget to clear it after your test.

Comment: Is there an annotation that I could use to set up a Context while writing my unit tests? The only annotation I needed to use before this problem was JUnit's @ExtendWith(Mockito)

Comment: Setting the context and clearing yourself is a lot faster than using the spring testing as that is more aimed at integration testing.

Comment: Understood, so it will be better to just add a @Before method to set up the SecurityContext? Thanks

Comment: Try adding `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` instead as a minimum starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `@ContextConfiguration` to load Spring Security test configuration into the Application Context(assuming you also have `spring-test`as a dependency)[See for clarification](http://@ContextConfiguration%20instructs%20the%20spring-test%20the%20configuration%20to%20use%20to%20create%20the%20ApplicationContext.%20Since%20no%20configuration%20is%20specified,%20the%20default%20configuration%20locations%20will%20be%20tried).

You can use the annotation `@SpringJUnitConfig` to combine the required annotations -- `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` and `@ContextConfiguration` -- to setup spring test in your tests.